# Where is this web pages located/ hosted?

Tags: router, wireless-router, hosts-file, gateway, adsl-router

when I type 192.168.154.154 (some 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1) on my browser, it gives me some web pages that (sort of) controls the setting/ options on my router. Now my questions are:

1. Where is this web pages hosted at ?

   - Is it located/ hosted on at the router itself ? if Yes then how is it possible that the router can handle such things ?
   - Or is it located on some other remote servers ? (by remote servers I mean something like, hosted by hosting companies like host gator)

Answer (score 4):

There's a web server on your *consumer* router - it makes it easier to configure things. It quite literally listens in on port 80 (usually only for IP ranges it serves) unless set otherwise.

The modern consumer router is pretty much literally a small single board arm or mips PC running a linux or embedded OS suite with software running for a local web server, routing, firewall and so on.